# UWP CameraCaptureUI - default camera

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to set the default camera to use with the CameraCaptureUI API?
On my dev tablet, the default camera is the front and I need to use the back camera.
It seems to be no parameter in the camera application to specify the default camera.
Also is there a way to launch the CameraCaptureUI in full screen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. `CameraCaptureUI` does not expose this level of control. Everything is handled by the system so the user will have to select the camera.

If you want to select the camera yourself from your code, you will have to use the lower level API `MediaCapture`.

You can find a first walkthough here : [Basic photo, video, and audio capture with MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture)

You will see an example of what you are looking for in this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit).

Here is a trim down sample code :

```
var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
_mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };
await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
```

Comment: If I don't want to manage camera in my app, is it possible to change the default camera used by the camera app. I don't see any settings to do it in the app...